# Javascript object variable is not available in object method

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying my hand at javascript objects. Funny enough when I am trying to use variable inside of methods it tells me either their are undefined or the that the method cannot be found.

```
var oPdf = {
  hFolderHandle: DocsList.getFolderById('0B1rbQnVtcj5CNWNmekFWMG9DZzA'),
  hTempHtmlHandle: "",
  hPdfHandle: "",

  mToastFeedback: function () {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Finished');
  }
};
oPdf.hTempHtmlHandle = oPdf.hFolderHandle.createFile('test.html', oInvoice.sInvoiceBody, 'text/html');
oPdf.hPdfHandle = oPdf.hFolderHandle.createFile(oPdf.hTempHtmlHandle.getAs('application/pdf')).rename('test.pdf');
DocsList.getFileById(oPdf.hTempHtmlHandle.getId()).setTrashed(true);
```

For example if I would have moved the line `oPdf.hTempHtmlHandle = oPdf.hFolderHandle.createFile('test.html', oInvoice.sInvoiceBody, 'text/html');` into a method 
inside the oPdf, like so:

```
 mTestMethod:function () {
      oPdf.hTempHtmlHandle = oPdf.hFolderHandle.createFile('test.html', oInvoice.sInvoiceBody, 'text/html');
 },
```

The Google Apps Script tells me that hFolderHandle doesn't know the method createFile.

Any ideas?

---

OK this works, just fine in the example above, but here it doesn't and I have no idea, why.

```
var oSpreadSheetApp = {
    hSpreadSheet: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(), //Retrieving the handle to the currently open spread-sheet
    hInvoiceSheet: this.hSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Rechnungen')
};
```

Comment: Use `this.hTempHtmlHandle = ...`

Comment: Please post a complete example and show how/where you call that method.

Comment: You are absolutely right pc-shooter... I feel pretty stupid now. You want to answer this so I can accept it?

Comment: I just came across another example that doesn't work, will edit question.

Comment: Well, in the new example, `this` doesn't refer to `oSpreadSheetApp` so that can't work. In the first example, putting the code in a method won't work if you are assigning a different value to `oPdf` in the meantime.

Comment: Color me ignorant, but I have not yet grasped the concept of 'this.' yet fully, care to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this . `this` is a special variable inside functions and its value depends on how the function is called.

Comment: This actually helped quite a bit. It is not straight forward, but logical never the less I modified the code now it works there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your method `mTestMethod` is part of the  `oPdf` object, you may access it like any property or method by calling `this` (**edit**: or `oPdf`) which is the "pointer" to the object.

**EDIT after comments:**

The problem is that `oPdf.hFolderHandle` or `this.hFolderHandle` does not know any method called `createFile()`.

---

```
mTestMethod:function () {
     // calling with the object itself  
     oPdf.hTempHtmlHandle = oPdf.hFolderHandle.createFile('test.html', oInvoice.sInvoiceBody, 'text/html');
     // or calling by 'this' is the same
      this.hTempHtmlHandle = oPdf.hFolderHandle.createFile('test.html', oInvoice.sInvoiceBody, 'text/html');
 },
```

---

Thx alot to **Felix Kling** for pointing at!

---

**Update after question update**

And this code:

```
var oSpreadSheetApp = {
    hSpreadSheet: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(), //Retrieving the handle to the currently open spread-sheet
    hInvoiceSheet: this.hSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Rechnungen')
};
```

should then be

```
var oSpreadSheetApp = {
    hSpreadSheet: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(), //Retrieving the handle to the currently open spread-sheet
    hInvoiceSheet: SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Rechnungen')
};
```

Because apparently the `SpreadsheetApp` here is **not** part of the object `oSpreadSheetApp`.

Comment: Even though this is the accepted answer, it should be noted that `this.hTempHtmlHandle` is no different than `oPdf.hTempHtmlHandle`. So if this solution works, the original code should have worked as well.